# Custom namespace for view in android xml

Tags: android

Here I made my own custom widgets in android and they all work fine. However, i have like 20 xml files and I don't want to change the `EditText` in xml to `com.example.customwidget.MyEditText` in all the xml layouts that I have. Any fast way to do that?

For example:
The below xml won't work. It will crash the application because there is no `MyEditText` in the android sdk widgets, that's my own widget.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </MyEditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However,
This one will work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.customwidget.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </com.example.customwidget.MyEditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I would like to do is to simply keep the `EditText` tag in the xml. However, I want to by my own custom `EditText`.

Ok I know I will have to change the class name first to be `EditText` instead of `MyEditText` but how can I let all the XML Layout files **know** that I want my custom `EditText` and not the native one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement custom [`LayoutInflater.Factory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html) and set it to [your activity's `LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFactory(android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory))

Here is an example of such factory:

```
public class MyLayoutInflaterFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory
{
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        if ("EditText".equals(name))
            return new MyEditText(context, attrs);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you need to use it in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ⋮

     LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(this)
            .cloneInContext(this)
            .setFactory(new MyLayoutInflaterFactory());

         setContentView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_activity, null));
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater()
    {
        return layoutInflater;
    }

    ⋮
}
```

Comment: no that's not what I want i'm sure you got me wrong. All I want is that when I use `EditText` in xml it won't use the native EditText it will use My `EditText` that I modified

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Comment: ah i think i'm starting to get you now.. but i have no idea how to do it,  any tip is appreciated :)

Comment: The `LayoutInflater.Factory.onCreateView` gets a name that is found in the XML. If that name is "EditText", you would create your `EditText` (using supplied context and attribute set), otherwise you would just return `null` and let the original factory create other views.

Comment: Ok thank you i'll try to do it and will post a solution when done

Comment: ok I couldn't make it. can you please provide me with an example?? please??? thank you

Comment: I have added an example